# Generic shared resource locking techniques - is flock the solution?

Tags: linux, lock

I need to implement a locking scheme so that multiple processes can share a set of resources, while a "special" process can obtain exclusive access to that set of resources.

These are batch processes: at the beginning of each transaction I propose to acquire the appropriate lock, and release it at the end, ad infinitum.

`flock` has the semantics I need (LOCK_SH, LOCK_EX, LOCK_UN). I experimented with it using Perl Flock.pm and a dummy file whose only purpose is to be `flock`'ed against. I was a little surprised at how slow it was, and it wasn't evident from 'top' where the time was being spent. (It wasn't CPU-bound, even though the loop being executed consisted of nothing but LOCK_SH and LOCK_UN.) I don't want to be guilty of premature optimization, but I wanted to know whether `flock` is the standard method for managing shared and exclusive access to a shared resource in *nix, even when the shared resource is not an actual file, or whether there was another facility I'm unaware of.

**UPDATE**: @msw correctly guessed that I'd (inadvertently) locked on an NFS file instead of a local one. Using a local file completely cleared up the performance hit I was seeing. I'm leaving the question open to learn more about whether "file locking" is really the best way to go for this class of problem.

Comment: Is this file accessed across the net, for example, NFS or SMB/CIFS? There are a number of processes that have to coordinate flocks across those protocols and it will, of necessity, be slower than a local file.

Comment: You nailed it! Yes, the file was on an NFS mount, rather than the local file system. Using a local file, it flies. Thanks.

Answer (score 6):

Unix has a plethora of locking systems. The one you found is called BSD file locking, but there are [other](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_locking#In_Unix-like_systems) file locking methods. On top of that, you also have [semaphores](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semaphore_(programming)), [mutexes](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mutual_exclusion) and more.

As to your direct question, yes, it is a perfectly fine way to go. Don't worry about the time it takes. Locking is a high-overhead activity, by its very nature. This is why so much effort goes into designing [lock-free](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Non-blocking_algorithm) mechanisms.

The only thing that bugs me about your plan is the dummy file you have to create. There may be a simpler way that achieves your desired end: `mkdir(2)`. The call is atomic, and you get an error when the directory already exists. By contrast, `open(2)` is [only atomic with `O_EXCL`](http://linux.die.net/man/2/open), which isn't available everywhere. When available, it may not work as expected, either because you are using NFSv2 or because you haven't enabled the [NFS file locking daemon](http://docstore.mik.ua/orelly/networking_2ndEd/nfs/ch07_05.htm).

Once nice thing about the `mkdir` approach is that you can do it in shell scripts, via `mkdir(1)`. I see that you're using Perl instead, but in that case, it's a built-in function, rather than an outside module.

Another nice thing is that it will work over NFS without any special help. You can't create a directory twice.

The only problem with the `mkdir()` approach is that there's no way to make it wait for an existing directory to disappear. That is, it is not a blocking lock operation. I suggest that you wrap it with a timer, so that the processes contending for the lock spend most of their time asleep. I suggest that you make each process wait a random windowed period of time. For instance, between 100 and 200 ms, via [`usleep(3)`](http://linux.die.net/man/3/usleep). This would create a form of [spinlock](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spinlock).

Comment: @msw pointed me to the solution to the performance problem (see above - I was inadvertently using an NFS-mounted file!). The eventual solution will be coded in C, so Perl and shell won't apply. I'm not sure I fully understand your preference for mkdir, since it doesn't naturally provide queue-until-available behavior for an EXCL lock, and requires spinning. Can you elaborate on the drawbacks to flock?

Comment: @Chap: I made that suggestion because a) you mentioned Perl; and b) you're posting this on Unix.SE and not Stack Overflow. Given all that, you should probably be using a semaphore or mutex, and not any of these file-based alternatives.

Comment: I'm definitely looking for a Linux C solution. But having looked at [this doc](http://www.comptechdoc.org/os/linux/programming/c/linux_pgcmutex.html), mutexes appear to be used for coordinating between threads, rather than processes.

Comment: There are more flavors of mutex than just pthread mutexes. [This one](http://www.thinkingparallel.com/2006/08/21/scoped-locking-vs-critical-in-openmp-a-personal-shootout/), for a start. Myself, I'd actually reach for a [POSIX semaphore](http://linux.die.net/man/7/sem_overview) instead. But keep in mind, this is not a classroom or a discussion forum. This is a site where you ask a well-focused question and get one (or hopefully more) well-focused answers.

Comment: To support @WarrenYoung's point, using files or directories as poor man's semaphores dates back to when semaphores didn't (portably) exist. If I found myself needing a mutex on the local machine, I'd probably use a POSIX semaphore because that's they were invented for.

Comment: It's fun that you mentionned mkdir, it's the one I've been using for ages precisely because it works in scripts, is portable, and is human-debuggable and fixable. It also allows you to store your context in the directory (you often need to keep some temporary data when you have to play with locks).